# How to fix "An array initializer of length '13' is expected"

Tags: c#

I'm trying to store all my answers to a question in a two-dimensional array. But I'm getting the problem:
"An array initializer of length '13' is expected".

I've tried changing the syntax but haven't found any way that it works.

```
string[,] answerCombinations; 
            answerCombinations = new string[,]
            {
                {
                    "kanes",
                    "skean",
                    "snake",
                    "sneak",
                    "kane",
                    "kens",
                    "sank",
                    "kaes",
                    "keas",
                    "sake",
                    "anes",
                    "sane",
                    "naes"

                }, 
                {
                    "more",
                    "omer",
                    "mor",
                    "rem",
                    "rom",
                    "ore",
                    "roe",
                    "emo"
                }


            };
```

Comment: I suggest you have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597720/what-are-the-differences-between-a-multidimensional-array-and-an-array-of-arrays).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2d array defined with [,] should have the same number of columns. You can do this instead:

```
string[][] answerCombinations; 
            answerCombinations = new string[][]
            {
                new string[]{
                    "kanes",
                    "skean",
                    "snake",
                    "sneak",
                    "kane",
                    "kens",
                    "sank",
                    "kaes",
                    "keas",
                    "sake",
                    "anes",
                    "sane",
                    "naes"

                }, 
                new string[]{
                    "more",
                    "omer",
                    "mor",
                    "rem",
                    "rom",
                    "ore",
                    "roe",
                    "emo"
                }


            };
```